# How to choose AWS EC2 instance with highest bandwidth for downloads?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, bandwidth

I am about to create a new Ubuntu Server EC2 instance. However, there appears to be very little information regarding the bandwidth available for each instance type. The server will be primarily used to download files from web urls, so download bandwidth will be critically important. What is the best way to determine which EC2 instance to create based on bandwidth available for downloading?

As a side note, I am considering the following EC2 instances which meet my hardware requirements: m4.large, m3.large, c4.large, or c3.large ([EC2 details here](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/))

Comment: How much bandwidth are we talking about?   Even a t2.nano should be able to push past 100 Mbits/s (12.5 MB/s).

Answer (score 1):

Spin up instances of various types and test them with your expected application and configuration. With spot instances, it's likely that you could test a significant portion of the available instance types with less than $5 US.

Comment: Using a load testing website or program would help here. Also CPU capacity isn't always critical for downloads, but if you have lots of simultaneous users you may need a large instance to get access to 10Gbps networking. It could also be cheaper and more fault tolerant to have a bunch of t2 instances behind a load balancer.

Comment: Or just serve files directly out of S3 and not have to worry about server performance at all.